# How do I restore the tab to Increase Indent Level in Keynote '13?

Tags: keyboard, macos, keynote

As of Keynote '13 for Mavericks, it seems Apple disabled <kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd> to increase indent level (and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>+<kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd> to decrease it).

Is there any way to re-enable this? I tried using the Keyboard Shortcuts control, but you cannot set <kbd>⇥ Tab</kbd> as a keyboard shortcut (it instead just moves you to the next control).

Comment: ⇥ and ⇧⇥ work fine for me - I don't think it's been removed :)

Comment: Tab inserts a tab now. Are you running the new Mavericks version?

Comment: Hmm... it seems like it just borked all of the existing templates. Using a new template, tab increases indent.

Comment: I have this same issue where tabs insert a tab without increasing the indent... and I have to use the indent button to get the bullets feature to behave correctly from the master template. This was confusing me a great deal as bullets weren't working correctly per the master template formatting... until I figured out the issue was with the tab key response. The issue is associated with keynote files updated from 09. I haven't found a solution yet to get the tab working to drive indentation.

Comment: I have tried editing an existing template and the behavior turns from tab to increase indent level to tab inserts a tab character. Looks like a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a great deal of testing, I have come to the conclusion that tab works to increase indent, but ONLY if your master slide is configured to have bullets. My solution (since I did not really want bullets on my slides) was to turn on bullets and set the color opacity to 0.

Answer (score 2):

I had decimal tabs bult into a text block and when using the Tab key, it pushed lines from the far left.

Holding the OPTION key don while tabbing makes it work correctly....Bizarre behavior

Answer (score 0):

I have this same issue where tabs insert a tab without increasing the indent... and I have to use the indent button to get the bullets feature to behave correctly from the master template. This was confusing me a great deal as bullets weren't working correctly per the master template formatting... until I figured out the issue was with the tab key response. The issue is associated with keynote files updated from 09. I haven't found a solution yet to get the tab working to drive indentation

Comment: I have given up on using files brought over from '09 and am just making a new master from scratch. So, with bullets turned on, the behavior still does not work right on files from '09?